# Python Pyramid periodic task

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, pyramid

My question is about how to perform a simple task in Pyramid Python framework?

I have a table with users birthdays and I'd like to check daily if someone's birthday is coming, and if so, print a simple greeting.

So I've defined some stuff in my views.py:

```
def print_greetings():
   tomorrow = datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    users = sess.query(User).filter(func.DATE_FORMAT(User.bday, "%d_%m")==tomorrow.strftime("%d_%m")).all()
    if len(users) > 0:
        for u in users:
            print("Happy Birthday", u.name)
```

So the question is:
How and where should I write something for execute this function once a day?

UPD: I need to run the task from the Pyramid app, external tools like cron are not the thing i'm looking for.

Maybe some sort of timer which will execute print_greetings()? And after execution will start a new instance of timer?

Comment: With your "in Pyramid" approach things are going to get a bit funny once you go beyond serving the application with pserve on your dev machine. A production webserver often spawns multiple "worker" processes/threads, which then can be killed or re-spawned at any time. A worker is not really supposed to do anything beyond the normal request/response cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Celery is a rather "heavy-weight" solution for a task like this, I'd recommend using [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You can setup the scheduler exactly like in cron, but it will run within your app. In this case the in-memory job store works fine.

```
import atexit
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(print_greetings,
    id='greetings', 
    name='Send out birthday greetings', 
    trigger='cron', 
    minute=0, 
    hour=12,
)

atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the the right thing I searched for

Answer (score 2):

For a python solution, check out [Celery Beat](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#introduction).

For something simpler, you can just create a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) with the schedule `0 0 * * *`. This will cause your script to run at midnight everyday.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script wrapping your Pyramid functionality as part of the framework (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#writing-a-script); this would allow you to have a standalone function that still is able to access your pyramid nuts and bolts.  But per your update, it's still going to be a standalone script that would need to be scheduled via some sort of task scheduler.

Unless I'm missing something, Pyramid isn't "always running" to the point where you could have a timer or sorts...you've got a server serving up requests that get processed by Pyramid.  I guess you could do something like have a Pyramid response that you hit ones that fires up a timer or something and then just runs infinitely but that seems like a bad way of going about things.  Even the script idea above - you could execute it once and have a timer launched and have it run infinitely, but then you've got a process constantly running.

A much better solution would be to have a scheduled task as has been suggested write out the current days' birthdays to a table, and then in your view query that table for display.